# javascript: Google Closure - RichTextEditor plugin

Tags: javascript, rich-text-editor, google-closure-library

I am making a custom plugin for the rich texteditor which sets a span with a certain class to a selected text, like:
    `<span class="myclass">text</span>`

Ok, so pretend I have the following text:

```
This is a test.
```

Now after selecting test and clicking the button to trigger my plugin it will output:

```
This is a <span class="myclass">test</span>.
```

Now after this I select the whole text and click the button again, this will output:

```
<span class="myclass">This is a <span class="myclass">test</span>.</span>
```

Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: What is the desired behavior? Is it to remove the inner `<span class="myclass"></span>` around the word "test"?

Answer (score 0):

You could use my [Rangy](http://code.google.com/p/rangy) library and its [class applier module](https://code.google.com/p/rangy/wiki/CSSClassApplierModule).

```
var applier = rangy.createCssClassApplier("myclass");
applier.applyToSelection();
```